# Prevent dynamic change of <td> content from text to an <input> element from expanding the width of the column

Tags: css, svelte

I have this Svelte snipped (also available in the Svelte repl [here](https://svelte.dev/repl/a46c80d698644fb0b93da772aa475fe1?version=3.36.0)]

```
<script>
  const rows = 10
  const cols = 5
  let clickedRow = -1
  let clickedCol = -1

  function clicked(row, col) {
    clickedRow = row
    clickedCol = col
  }

  function clear() {
    clickedCol = -1
    clickedRow = -1
  }
</script>

<table>
    {#each Array(rows) as _, row}
        <tr>
            {#each Array(cols) as _, col}
                <td on:click={() => clicked(row, col)}>
                    {#if clickedRow === row && clickedCol === col}
                        <input type="text" value="Hello" />
                    {:else}
                        Hello {row}.{col}
                    {/if}
                </td>
            {/each}

        </tr>
    {/each}
</table>

<button on:click={clear}>Clear</button>

<style>
    table, tr, td {
        border: solid 1px
    }
</style>
```

When you click a table cell, it switches to an `<input>` element, simulating the ability to edit the data.  But the `<td>` gets wider once the `<input>` id added, causing the whole column to get wider.  This is a jumpy experience for the user.

How do I change the content of the `<td>` without widening the column?

In other words, once the table is sized to fit the content, how do I keep the width of each column fixed, even if I change the contents of a cell?

Comment: Here is one possible implementation, but very much open to a more native CSS solution: https://svelte.dev/repl/b70b8306d84547e882756f6576b853f3?version=3.36.0

Comment: So...you're looking to have the table size dynamically on DOM load, but locked in place after?

Comment: Perfect description of my need @JasonHoltzen !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `width: 0; min-width: 100%;` trick can help you.

```
input {
    width: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

[Repl](https://svelte.dev/repl/82b9d3b2eb9e4c66ac7802b65f520af8?version=3.37.0)

Comment: That is super close @doğukan, but the height of the input elements truncates some of the text if it contains the character 'g' - see amended [repl](https://svelte.dev/repl/536537cba3af47b6a8fecfd38253dfeb?version=3.37.0)

Comment: can you try that https://svelte.dev/repl/82b9d3b2eb9e4c66ac7802b65f520af8?version=3.37.0

Comment: Pertect @doğukan, it works great!  Thank you so much.